# Two TypeScript functions with static return types. Syntax differs, but they seem to do the same thing?

Tags: typescript, function, types, static, return

I'm learning TypeScript and am trying to define a function with a static return type and some static parameters. Both of these definitions seem to do that, but the syntax is different. Why? Do these differ in some way that I'm missing?

```
// function with statically typed parameters and return type defined
function addNums(n1: number, n2: number, n3: number): void 
{
    let sum = n1 + n2 + n3;
    alert(sum);
}

// This seems to accomplish the same thing but needlessly more complex
let alsoAddNums : (one: number, two: number, three: number) => void 
    = function(n1, n2, n3) 
    {
        let sum = n1 + n2 + n3;
        alert(sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first one is a function definition, and the second one is a variable, that has a function assigned to it. that's what you do, if you need to store a reference to a function:

```
function addNums(n1: number, n2: number, n3: number): void 
{
    let sum = n1 + n2 + n3;
    alert(sum);
}

let alsoAddNums : (one: number, two: number, three: number) => void = addNums
```

interaction with both of them is identical.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Why would you want to store a reference when you could just call the function directly? Seems to me that you'd still need to add all the same arguments when using the reference.

Comment: it is necessary for higher order functions, for example.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Much Appreciated.

Comment: please don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.